# Update SeekBar with EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, seekbar

i'm developing an BMI calculator and i added an optional SeekBar to change the values from the edittext. When i move the seekbar the values from the edittext are different, but the seekbar doesn't update when i change the from the edittext.

Could osmeone explcain how can i do that? I'm having problems with getText and SetProgress

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private RadioGroup rgsexo;
EditText editPeso;
EditText editAltura;
TextView imcView;
SeekBar alterarAltura;
SeekBar alterarPeso;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editPeso = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPeso);
    editAltura = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editAltura);
    imcView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imcView);
    alterarAltura = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.alterarAltura);
    alterarPeso = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.alterarPeso);
    alterarAltura.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(alteraralturaListener);
    alterarPeso.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(alterarpesoListener);
    //This is where i'm having troubles
    editAltura.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            double setAltura = (editAltura.getText.toString()) * .01d;
            alterarAltura.setProgress(String.format("%.02f", setAltura).replace(',', '.'));
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    }); 
}

private OnSeekBarChangeListener alteraralturaListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
    boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        double setAltura = (alterarAltura.getProgress()) * .01d;
        // mostra na caixa o valor novo
        editAltura.setText(String.format("%.02f", setAltura).replace(',', '.'));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have Used Two way Function it will affect the Both function i executed the this program I have changed the small modification in this program...

You just Enter the Text it will change the Seek bar automatically.......

**And you have to set the Maximum value of the Seek bar then only you can change the Seek bar Progress...all the best...**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private EditText mTextEditer;
private SeekBar mSeekBar;
public float mProgressText;
public int mProgressValue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextEditer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textEditer);
    mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    mSeekBar.setMax(100);
    mTextEditer.addTextChangedListener(new watcher());
    mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public class watcher implements TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        try {
            if (s != null) {
                mProgressText = Float.parseFloat(s.toString());
                mProgressValue = (int) mProgressText;
                mSeekBar.setProgress(mProgressValue);
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            mSeekBar.setProgress(0);
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

}
```