# Update EditText in a list view with value from a SeekBar

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have a ListView and each row item comprises of a SeekBar and an EditText (as in figure below). I need to update the EditText based on the seekbar's value, which I'm able to do if I have both the widget references without a problem.

My issue is how do I associate each seekbar to its correct EditText box? Both these widgets are part of a view that I inflate in my adapter. Referencing an EditText directly doesn't seem to be a good idea because of Android's view recycling in the ListView.

What is the best way forward?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you show each pair of SeekBar and editText just use

```
seekBar.setTag(editText);
editText.setTag(seekBar);
```

and when update something use

```
seekBar = (SeekBar)editText.getTag();
seekBar.setProgress(...);
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the best solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

[Change SeekBar progress based on EditText value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802397/change-seekbar-progress-based-on-edittext-value)

here was the same issue

[Update SeekBar with EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185421/update-seekbar-with-edittext)

here was the same issue too

Comment: This was not my question. The problem I'm facing is that both the EditText and Seekbar elements are part of a row item in the ListView that I inflate in my adapter. How do I get the reference is the question.

Comment: set id to them and refere then? can u post this part of ur code ?

Comment: The references would become invalid if the view gets recycled.

Answer (score 0):

Set a `OnSeekBarChangeListener` to the `SeekBar` that change the `TextView`'s text when `OnProgressChanged()` is called. Do this in the `getView()` in the `Adapter`.