# Android SeekBar in ListView using tags

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, seekbar, listadapter

Well, I have a seekBar into a custom listview, and I'm using the setTag/getTag method on my onChangeClickListener, just as suggested [here in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802173/update-edittext-in-a-list-view-with-value-from-a-seekbar) and works fine. But **when I add a new element** to the listView, the seekbar of the new element takes the progress of the element that previously was on its position.

**Note that my `SeekBar sbAnalog` updates my `EditText etAnalogPosition` and vice-versa**

Here is my `getView()` code:

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            view = convertView;


            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_list_layout, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.sbAnalog = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.sbAnalog);
                holder.etAnalogPosition = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAnalogPosition);

                view.setTag(holder);

            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
            holder.sbAnalog.setTag(holder.etAnalogPosition);
            holder.etAnalogPosition.setTag(holder.sbAnalog);

            holder.sbAnalog.setMax(list.get(position).getMax());


                holder.sbAnalog.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                        EditText et = (EditText) seekBar.getTag();
                        et.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                        list.get(position).setPosition(i);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }
                });
            }
holder.etAnalogPosition.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                        if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                            int value = 0;
                            try {
                                value = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                SeekBar sb = (SeekBar )textView.getTag();
                                value = sb.getProgress();
                            }
                            //if (value > list.get(position).getMax())
                            //value = list.get(position).getMax();
                            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) textView.getTag();
                            sb.setProgress(value);
                            textView.clearFocus();

                            if (view != null) {
                                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                            }

                        textView.setText(String.valueOf(sb.getProgress()));
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });}
```

Need help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that the best way to solve is adding this two lines to the code:

```
holder.sbAnalog.setProgress(list.get(position).getPosition());

holder.etAnalogPosition.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getPosition()));
```

Note that every element of my list is a custom Object that I created, which one has a `getPosition()` method that basically returns the seekBar's position of the element, setted by a `setPosition()` method.

So if you are having the same problem, I recommend you to make it this way, or simply create an arrayAdapter that stores every element's position, so you'll be able to `set` and `get` just as I did im my `getView()` code.

*Hope it helps!*